# Pointer to the element in the list VS element itself

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have found this code on the internet and I need a little help with it.
Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

/* Linked list structure */
struct list {
struct list *prev;
int data;
struct list *next;
} *node = NULL, *first = NULL, *last = NULL, *node1 = NULL, *node2 = NULL;

class linkedlist {
public: 

    /* Function for create/insert node at the beginning of Linked list */
    void insert_beginning() {
        list *addBeg = new list;
        cout << "Enter value for the node:" << endl;
        cin >> addBeg->data;
        if(first == NULL) {
            addBeg->prev = NULL;
            addBeg->next = NULL;
            first = addBeg;
            last = addBeg;
            cout << "Linked list Created!" << endl;
        }


        else {
            addBeg->prev = NULL;
            first->prev = addBeg;
            addBeg->next = first;
            first = addBeg;
            cout << "Data Inserted at the beginning of the Linked list!" << endl;
        }
    }
```

What I don't understand is when he is making the new Node object (in this case it's **addBeg**) he is putting a pointer operator in front of it. And how I'm seeing it now, shouldn't the object be created without the '*' before it's name and with the data, pointer to next and pointer to the previous one, unlike the pointer to the node in the list which should only contain address of the node, without any other data ? If that's not the case, then what is the thing that differs the pointer to the node in the list from the node itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it's been done in the code is correct.  You are having an incorrect understanding in that the data of a node cannot be accessed through the pointer to that node.

If `addBeg` is the pointer pointing to the node returned by `new list`, then the data of that node can be accessed using the operator `->`:

`list.data` is equivalent to `addBeg->data`.

*`If that's not the case, then what is the thing that differs the pointer to the node in the list from the node itself ?`*

=> `addBeg` is the pointer pointing to an object, that object being returned by `new List`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't interpret this C++ declaration correctly... the meaning of code

```
 list *addBeg = new list;
```

is

```
 list* addBeg;
 addBeg = new list;
```

`list*` in other words is the type of `addBeg`.

Note that the rules are indeed strange, because while the `*` being logically attached to first `list` to form the type, the meaning of

```
list *a, b;
```

will declare `a` to be a "pointer to list" and b to be a "instance of list" instead (so the meaning is attached to `list` but the star itself is attached to `a`).

Some programmers go quite far about this and:

1. They always put the star attached to the type (on the left)
2. They never declare two variables in the same construct

In my experience after writing enough code this interpretation problem will however disappear and even crazy syntax rule for C/C++ declarations will be reasonable easy to read (at least in simple cases).